# Incorrect JSON formatting from device

Tags: javascript, json, object

A device sends the following JSON:

```
{
  "Order": ""3"",
  "ID":    ""SHEET"",
  "Name":  ""Time Sheet"",
  "ConID": ""!s?d2SzxcSDW1cf$*@4812sC#""
}
```

As you can see, the property values are messed up with two double quotes around each value.

Is there any way to parse or reformat this device response into a valid object?

I tried to replace `""` to `"\"` but am not sure whether it matched exactly or not.

Comment: If its not a proper object then you need to do string parsing. like split with `","` and then again split by `":"` Pick the first as key and second as value.

Comment: It's not valid JSON. You should find out if it can be corrected at the source.

Comment: Or maybe it is a valid JSON, but the person is not showing us the JSON itself, but JSON in some "JSON viewer" https://imgur.com/Ge4GSUe

Comment: @IvanKuckir are you expecting me that i am not showing you `\"` because of i did not know about json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to replace all occurrences of `""` with `"` using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex to ensure global replacement, and then use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
let json = '{"Order":""3"","ID":""SHEET"","Name":""Цагийн бүртгэл"","ConID":""!s?d2SzxcSDW1cf$*@4812sC#""}';
json = json.replace(/""/g, '"');
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: wow i tried with backslash like this `"\", "\"\""` guess it was wrong after all thanks

Comment: I edited my source from device i all keep it in later

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar I'm glad you were able to fix it on your device. It'll make your life a lot easier in the long run. Thanks for accepting the answer regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the device that sends the invalid JSON response uses a software that takes values (regardless of what they contain) and fills them into the response's property values, always surrounded by double quotes.

If you have access to the code that generates the device's JSON, try to find the piece of code that generates the final JSON. Two possible solutions exist:

- remove inner double quotes from original strings (improper solution)
- remove outer double quotes (this way, numbers will also stay numbers and not be converted into strings)

In case you might have no access to the device source code generating the JSON, please use [@Nick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57706778/2764486) to get rid of the double double quotes.

Comment: i fixed this json editing source code of device if i haven't i probably use nick's answer. Here you go upvote